# Error en formato de fecha en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime, cshtml

Tengo unas variables de tipo Datetime almacenadas, cuyo valor cuando hago debug está en el siguiente formato(obviamente):`{11/11/2020 00:00:00}`. Estas en BD están de la siguiente: `2020-11-17 09:06:04.0`

Hasta ahí todo perfecto, el problema es al intentar sacarlo en una tabla por pantalla mediante Javascript. El código de la tabla es el siguiente:

```
                    self.cols = [
                        { field: "usuario", title: "Usuario", filter: { usuario: "text" }, sortable: "usuario", show: true },
                        { field: "fecha", title: "Fecha Inserción", filter: { fecha: "text" }, sortable: "fecha", show: true },
                    ];
```

Quizá sea el **fecha:"text"** pero en otras fechas está mostrando el formato de forma correcta con el mismo estilo.

A la hora de verse por pantalla, la fecha se visualiza así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en este caso la palabra fecha es el nombre de la variable, para que la pille.

Comment: Probaste envolviendo la variable que te trae la fecha con un `new Date()`? Algo como `new Date(fecha)`, si sólo estas usando JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas probable es que estas trabajando con un servidor en .NET, el formato por defecto en que .NET devuelve las fechas a través de JSON es en ese formato ([MomentJS](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/01-parsing/11-asp-net-json-date/), [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)).

Para solucionar este situación tienes que formatear el string que te entrega y cambiarlo a la clase Date de Javascript de la siguiente forma:

```
new Date(parseInt(fechaJSON.split('(')[1].replace(')', '').replace('/', '')))
```

Esta seria una forma un poco "sucia" de arreglarlo, pero funciona. La idea principal es obtener solo el numero entre los paréntesis y eso se lo pasas como parámetro a la clase `new Date()` y te retorna la fecha. (También puedes sacar los paréntesis y demás con [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp)).

Por ultimo, para solucionarte mas la vida te recomiendo uses la librería de [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/), esta es muy útil para trabajar con fechas en javascript que normalmente suele ser un dolor de cabeza.